# mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition not accepted after Imports AForge

Tags: vb.net, import

[When trying to run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oadMS.png)   [Error when: imports AForge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KGcFQ.png)

^^ 2 screenshots
 Well I hope to get a fix as I don't understand error.

```
Private Sub Form1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles MyBase.MouseMove

    If e.Button = MouseButtons.Left Then
        Dim mousePos As Point = Control.MousePosition
        mousePos.Offset(mouse_offset.X, mouse_offset.Y)
        Location = mousePos

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please visit the [help] to see how to write a good question; we can't debug screenshots! Provide a clear description of your problem, and include the code in the question itself.

Comment: According to your screenshot, what `Control` are you trying to get the mouse position from? Try `Dim mousePos As Point = Me.MousePosition`

Comment: All is fixed TnTinMn got the solution ;) cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably a namespace collision where AForge also has a Point type.  Fully qualify the reference.

`Dim mousePos As System.Drawing.Point = Control.MousePosition`

Comment: That's what I was guessing. Cheers all is working ;)